# illegal cyclic reference involving object thrift generated method params

Tags: scala, thrift, scala-reflect

I am trying to list all members of a thrift service endpoint's params.

```
 val paramsClass = mirror.staticClass("mytest.thrift.MyService.method_args")
    println(paramsClass.toType.members())
```

Then I got `illegal cyclic reference involving object method_args`

I wonder if this is because the method_args is a static class inside MyService. Is there a special way to get it?
I tried `val paramsClass = mirror.staticClass("mytest.thrift.MyService$method_args")`, get the same error immediately.

Could anyone please suggest how to resolve this?

Comment: are you missing an assignment operator?

Comment: What assignment operator? could you please point out in the code?@Bob Dalgleish

Comment: I don't see how the first statement is valid Scala. Are you assigning `mirror.staticClass()` to `paramsClass`? If so, there needs to be an assignment operator.

Comment: o, thanks, that's my typo, let me add that now.